# Problem with sending static js files to client browser with express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ckeditor

I want to develop a very basic blog app with express.js and I was trying to create a webpage where I could write a post from the browser and store it into a db after submitting it.

By searching on the internet I came upon the ckeditor package, which would allow me to format my blog post before submitting it to the database. I read the documentation and tried to integrate the package in the html code together with the javascript scripts necessary to load the software.

However, when I load the *new_post* page in my browser I see that the browser is not loading correctly the ckeditor even though I am serving the javascript script necessary to run it as a static resource through the *express.static* method.

Here you can find the necessary info to check my issue:

Project Structure:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74I1g.png)

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;

const newPostRouter = require(".\\routes\\new_post.js");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//Homepage
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("homepage", { title: "My Express App", message: "Hello World!" });
});

//Write a new post
app.use("/new-post", newPostRouter);

//Listener
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

routes/new_post.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const path = require("path");


router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("new_post");
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const content = req.body.content;
  res.redirect("/");
});

module.exports = router;
```

views\new_post.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/35.4.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="..\public\dog-img.jpg" alt="derp" />
    <h1>Classic editor</h1>
    <div id="editor">
      <p>This is some sample content.</p>
    </div>
    <script
      src="..\public\js_scripts\new_post.js"
      type="application\javascript"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

public\js_scripts\new_post.js

```
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#editor")).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

As you can see I am trying to send the static resources to the client browser by using the express.static method in the app.js file. However when I try to load the page in the browser, this is the result I get:

[result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPXnR.png)

The dog-img.jpg, also contained in the public folder, is correctly sent to the client yet the javascript file new_post.js is not.

I've also tried to modify the ejs file by substituting the script tag with

```
<script>
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#editor")).catch((error) => {
console.error(error);
});
</script>
```

When I do this the editor correctly loads in my browser:
[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OiiA.png)

Since I am trying to follow the best practices I'd like to keep my js files separated from the html/ejs files and therefore I'd like to call the scripts from an external source and not internally.

Can anybody help me understand what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't use backslashes in URL's and content types, use forward slashes.

Comment: @robertklep thank you, it was as simple as that, I've changed the code to 

<script
      src="../public/js_scripts/new_post.js"
      type="application/javascript"
    ></script>

and now it's working. So should I change all the slashes in my code, am I right?

Comment: In your Node.js code you probably have to keep using backslashes, but files that run in a browser (HTML, JS) should use forward slashes for things like (URL-)paths and mime types.

Answer (score 0):

In app.js you need to write

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

code to access all data inside the `asset` folder.

then you need to simple add or load this inside your `.ejs` file.

```
 <img src="/images/img1.jpg" alt="" srcset="">

 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />

 <script src='/javascripts/index.js'></script>
```

For More Details Please visit this link [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: This is more an opinion than an answer, some people just prefer to prefix their public files with `/public` (or whatever).

Comment: @robertklep, Okay, Should I edit my answer? or keep it , as it is.

Comment: You can edit it, but it's not clear how it would actually solve the problem.

Comment: @robertklep, Actually, I answered based on question and as per my mindset. I don't know how to better answer.

Comment: Please you can edit it or i will remove this answer after sometime